react navbar components alignment
well i have been stragling to align all the items of the navbar next to each other couldn't see where the problem is i tried to fix the size of the logo but it didn t work and the elements remaind on top of each other
here the css code
/************ Default Css ************/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-padding-top: 75px;
}

body {
  font-weight: 400;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #121212 !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  font-family: 'Centra', sans-serif !important;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: normal;
}

p, a, li, button, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus, select:focus {
  outline: none;
}

@media (min-width:1700px) {
    main .container {
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 0 150px;
    }
}

p.success {
    color: green;
}

p.danger {
    color: red;
}
/************ Navbar Css ************/


nav.navbar {/*Styles the overall navbar container*/
  padding: 18px 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  transition:  0.32s ease-in-out;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 18px 20px;
}
nav.navbar.scrolled {
  padding: 0px 0;
  background-color: #121212;
}
nav.navbar a.navbar-brand {/*Styles the logo container (Navbar.Brand)*/
    width: 0;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link.navbar-link {/*Styles individual navigation links*/
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff !important;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
  padding: 0 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
/*effects hover */
nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link:hover,
nav.navbar .navbar-nav a.nav-link.navbar-link.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
span.navbar-text {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.social-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 14px;
}
.social-icon a {
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    background: rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.1);
    display: inline-flex;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 6px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.social-icon a::before {
    content: "";
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: scale(0);
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.social-icon a:hover::before {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.social-icon a img {
    width: 40%;
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.social-icon a:hover img {
    filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(0%) sepia(7%) saturate(98%) hue-rotate(346deg) brightness(95%) contrast(86%);
}
.navbar-text button {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 18px 34px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 18px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-text button span {
  z-index: 1;
}
.navbar-text button::before {
  content: "";
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.navbar-text button:hover {
  color: #121212;
}
.navbar-text button:hover::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler:active,
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler-icon {
  width: 24px;
  height: 17px;
  background-image: none;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
  top: -2px;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler-icon:focus {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler-icon:after,
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
    width: 24px;
    position: absolute;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    content: '';
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
    top: 8px;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2px;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon:before {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(-45deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 2px;
}
nav.navbar .navbar-toggler[aria-expanded="true"] .navbar-toggler-icon {
    border-color: transparent;
}

and this the navbar component
return (
    
      <Navbar expand="md" className={scrolled ? "scrolled" : ""}>
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href="/">
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </Navbar.Toggle>
          <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ms-auto">
              <Nav.Link href="#home" className={activeLink === 'home' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('home')}>Home</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#skills" className={activeLink === 'skills' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('skills')}>Skills</Nav.Link>
              <Nav.Link href="#projects" className={activeLink === 'projects' ? 'active navbar-link' : 'navbar-link'} onClick={() => onUpdateActiveLink('projects')}>Projects</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <span className="navbar-text">
              <div className="social-icon">
                <a href="#"><img src={navIcon1} alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src={navIcon2} alt="" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src={navIcon3} alt="" /></a>
              </div>
              
                <button className="vvd"><span>Let’s Connect</span></button>
            
            </span>
          </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
    
  )

i m expecting all items like logo links and icons to be aligned
current situation
